# showing the normal number in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I plotted a heat map for the categorical variable as following. the number are showing with e and I want normal numbers to show. how can I fix this issue?

[image]

```
df2=df.copy()
df_heatmap = df2.pivot_table(values='Message_click',index='Message_TA',columns='Message_type',aggfunc=pd.Series.sum)
sns.heatmap(df_heatmap,annot=True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you `sns.heatmap(df_heatmap,annot=True,  fmt='g')`

fmt is a "String formatting code to use when adding annotations", from https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html